Summation by parts and small sums
Let $\chi$ be a Dirichlet character modulo $q$, and consider the Dirichlet series
$$L(s,\chi) = \sum_n \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}$$
We know that $\sum_{k < n} \chi(k) = o(n)$ for $n > q$ for instance, when $\chi$ is nontrivial. Apparently this should imply
$$
L(1, \chi) = \sum_{n<q} \frac{\chi(n)}{n} + o(\log q)
$$
but I don't see why. Trying summation by parts, formally, I get $\log(q) o(\sum_{n\geq X} n^{-1})$ (but this diverges).
Am I mistaken?

I think you need $\chi$ not trivial as otherwise the result is not true and then you forgot the orthogonality property $\sum_{n \le k < n+q}\chi(k)=0$; with this, you should be able to show your result

You also have the much stronger $\lvert \sum_{k \leq n} \chi(k) \rvert \leq q$, which follows from $\lvert \chi(k) \rvert \leq 1$ and $\sum_{1 \leq k \leq q} \chi(k) = 0$. If you use this instead, presumably you'll prove your result. (Actually, you'll prove something substantially stronger).

@davidlowryduda I tried to use this property indeed, but summing by parts I end up with $\sum_{n>q} (\sum_{k<n} \chi(k)) n^{-s-1}$, bounding the sum inside by $q$ and estimating the tail of the series then give $q \times q^{-s}$, am I wrong? I don't see any $\log q$

@Amomentum In the calculation of your comment, doesn't that give the even stronger error $O(1)$ at $s=1$?

@GregMartin I agree, this is why I am a bit worried. GRH seems to imply a bound of $\log\log q$ for $L(1, \chi)$, so I should be missing something...

That contribution comes from the sum over $n<q$, don't worry :)

@GregMartin Indeed, thanks a lot for opening my eyes!
